# W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

well my app working fine getting data from Firebase. but sometimes specially after waiting long time if I open my app again it wont read data from firebase and also it gives this warning at Logcat. until I sing in and sing out it is not working.

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
```

are there any missing lines on my gradle?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.restroomgames.whereismydudy.where"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.lapism:searchview:5.0.0-alpha7'
    implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Are you able to solve this error?i m facing the same with flutter stable release.

Comment: It's been a long time, but as far as I remember, this error had occurred because I didn't open one of the google APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems ok..

It just happened to me something similar, same warning, problems with email/password auth..

It was because I forgot to update the SHA-1 fingerprints in the project after I upgraded my computer OS..

Maybe is a problem with your API keys or SHA-1 fingerprints in your project?

Answer (score 0):

No there is nothing missing in your `Gradle`, this problem actually has come about since the upgrade to Firebase 11.6.0 Downgrading to 11.4.2 seems to remove the warning messages.